# wanted to post image from android to WCF rest service

Tags: android, wcf, post, wcf-rest

I want to upload or post a image file on server using REST WCF. For this I am using JSON as input format.

But when I am checking this post call with debugger due to Base64 image data input is not accepted by the debugger .

I was giving me the 400-Bad Request response for this call.

Thanks.

Comment: It's hard to say what's going on without code and service description.

Answer (score 0):

1. First understand the concept of JSON/REST.
2. Then Make your WCF method to input the Byte[] i.e. Byte Array.
3. Convert your Image in Base64 and Pass it to the REST.

In order to send Image to JSON Web Service, you need to convert that to Byte Array or Base 64 String Representation.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ya I'm Converting the image to base 64 format..
Still not working

Comment: So, in that case you need to make sure that the WCF accepts the similar argument. If you are sure that you've converted to Base 64 Then the victim is WCF